# SWR, creating a wrapper around the useSWR hook to show loading state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swr

I am using [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) in a React.js application and I find myself needing to display the loading status of a request.

I created a helper function that extracts the loading status from an `SWRResponse` similar to what SWR provides in their documentation [examples](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started#make-it-reusable):

```
const isLoading = ({ data, error }: SWRResponse<any, any>): boolean => {
    return data === undefined && error === undefined;
}
```

I would like to create a wrapper hook, that always adds this information in the return value, similar to the following:

```
const useSWRWithLoading: SWRHook = (...args) => {
    const swrResponse = useSWR(...args);
    return { ...swrResponse, isLoading: isLoading(swrResponse) };
};
```

Since I used the builtin type `SWRHook` I have no support for the `isLoading` value.

### How I tried solving the issue (without any success):

```
const useSWRWithLoading = (...args: Parameters<SWRHook>): ReturnType<SWRHook> & { isLoading: boolean } => {
    const swrResponse = useSWR(...args);

    return { ...swrResponse, isLoading: isLoading(swrResponse) };
};
```

or (this is pretty much the same thing as before)

```
type SWRHookWithLoading = (...args: Parameters<SWRHook>) => ReturnType<SWRHook> & { isLoading: boolean };

const useSWRWithLoading: SWRHookWithLoading = (...args) => {
    const swrResponse = useSWR(...args);

    return { ...swrResponse, isLoading: isLoading(swrResponse) };
};
```

One thing I noticed is that:

```
type Foo = Parameters<SWRHook>; // type Foo = never
type Bar = ReturnType<SWRHook>; // type Bar = SWRResponse<unknown,unknown>
```

And I don't know how to fix it.

If I try to make the `SWRHookWithLoading` Type a generic, I get an error that says: `Type 'SWRHook' is not generic.`.

```
type SWRHookWithLoading<Data = any, Error = any> = (...args: Parameters<SWRHook<Data, Error>>) => ReturnType<SWRHook<Data, Error>> & { isLoading: boolean };
```

This is puzzling for me because the type definition for `SWRHook` is:

```
export declare type SWRHook = <Data = any, Error = any>(...args: readonly [Key] | readonly [Key, Fetcher<Data> | null] | readonly [Key, SWRConfiguration<Data, Error> | undefined] | readonly [Key, Fetcher<Data> | null, SWRConfiguration<Data, Error> | undefined]) => SWRResponse<Data, Error>;
```

which looks like a generic for me.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a hook for each query, which then allows you to return custom values. In the example below, the function `useUser` returns the `data` property from the `useSWR` function as `user`, as well as custom properties `isLoading` and `isError`. `isLoading` is true when there is no error, but there is also no data. It is false if there is data, an error, or both.

```
function useUser (id) {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/user/${id}`, fetcher)

  return {
    user: data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    isError: error
  }
}
```

*Source: SWR Docs*

This approach also makes it easier to share queries between areas of your codebase.

Comment: FYI `useSWR` now directly return an `isLoading` property ;)